# How to avoid the ./ when executing a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, path

I used to know a way to run my shell scripts just by typing there name as long as there were in my home folder or desktop. I hate having to type `./myscript.sh`. I would like to be able to type just `myscript.sh`. How can I fix my terminal to do this?

I'm using GNOME Terminal and Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a bad idea to put the current directory into your path. Move your scripts that you want to frequently run into `~/bin` and then add `~/bin` to your path.

To do this, add:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

to `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @Lucas: It's no longer hard to find on Google :)

Comment: @MikeyB: SF saves the day again!

Answer (score 6):

You can add . to the path, but as MikeyB says, it is a bad idea.

The reason it is a dangerous thing to do is that if a malicious bit of software with the same name as an executable you are running exists in the current directory, that will be run instead.

Answer (score 3):

I put my shell scripts in /usr/local/bin, seems the best place for them? it's usually empty. Make them executable and forget the .sh extension, and you can just call them plainly.

That's on Ubuntu server.

Comment: /usr/local/bin is the right place for scripts that are meant for all users. ~/bin is for scripts for that user. Of course it doesn't matter if you're the only user...

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question that was asked, add your home directory and the desktop to the path.

Comment: +1, and the lesson is: be careful what you ask for :-)